# Is this UPDATE statement correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I get a little nervous writing some SQL, when it will affect so many customer records!

I have an orders table an a customer table. We sell two products, ProductA and ProductB. I want to clear all address records for customers that bought ProductA ONLY. Is this statement right:

```
UPDATE customers AS c
JOIN orders ON c.CustomerNumber = orders.CustomerNumber
SET
 c.Add1= '',
 c.Add2= '',
 c.PostCode= ''
WHERE
    orders.Product = 'ProductA'
```

Simple as that?

Comment: Friend there is no way we could know. We don't work on your system. It could be correct because you're stating that the `orders` product must be `ProductA` - but it's just not possible for us to know.

Comment: If you are afraid to update more than expected or the wrong rows, make sure you run this with auto-commit off, so that you can do a rollback if you touched the wrong rows.

Comment: duplicate your table and test this query on it

Comment: Or even simpler (can't believe no one suggested before), just do a `SELECT` instead of an `UPDATE` before...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Good advice, but worth caveating that one can only rollback transactional storage engines (i.e. InnoDB).

Comment: This will update all rows in ORDERS that have `ProductA`, regardless of whether customers have bought ProductB or not. I'm reading your requirements as only updating `ProductA` if there is not also a `ProductB` row for that customer.

Comment: Write it as a SELECT to check if the result is what you expect (it looks correct). I would also flag the rows as 'obsolete' or something instead of clearing the data.

Answer (score 1):

How about you make it a `SELECT` statement to see which records are to be affected?

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   customers AS c
  JOIN orders
    ON c.CustomerNumber = orders.CustomerNumber
WHERE  orders.Product = 'ProductA'
```

Answer (score 0):

No! it's not right, it will clear any customers that have bought product A, regardless of whether they also bought productb.

You need a select statement like

```
UPDATE customers AS c

SET
 c.Add1= '',
 c.Add2= '',
 c.PostCode= ''
WHERE
    c.CustomerNo in (select customerNo from orders where Orders.Product = 'ProductA')
    AND
    c.CustomerNo not in (select customerNo from orders where Orders.Product = 'ProductB')
```

You could probably do it more efficiently with joins, but if it's just a one off that should do it.

Check that

```
select * from customers

WHERE
    c.CustomerNo in (select customerNo from orders where Orders.Product = 'ProductA')
    AND
    c.CustomerNo not in (select customerNo from orders where Orders.Product = 'ProductB')
```

returns only customers you'd expect